# Any alternative to Google Maps API with directions from current location?

Tags: maps

I am currently developing a web site for my thesis which features my City's tourist spots (e.g. malls, parks, restaurants) with Google Maps API that shows the current location of the user and the destination point and all the possible routes to said destination. But sadly, with the Billing system I am limited to load a few maps before it says "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

I have researched few free Maps API and I have found some, like MapBox, HERE Api... What would be the best free alternative for Google Map API?

P.s. I am still a student and can not afford to pay $200. If there are any other possible ways in handling this, please do let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Freemium Plan from HERE Maps, 250.000 transactions/months for free, no need for credit card.
You can use JS, REST and Native APIs.

Comment: Does it also show directions from the user's current location to the destination just like Google Maps does?

Comment: Yes you have text instructions with REST/JS and you can do turn by turn with vocal guidance on iOS/Android